Google Scholar search strategy
Is there any way to search for specific keywords only in the Abstract in a Google Scholar search?
I am working on a systematic literature review, and trying to mine articles based on abstract search. I am aware of the title search, but not any regarding the abstract search. Any ideas?

I don't believe there is. In "advanced search" you can search the whole article or just the title, but not, AFAIK, the abstract.

For systematic reviews, I would avoid Google Scholar. It's useful for grey literature searches and getting quick answer when writing, but that's about it. The search algorithm is very opaque and it doesn't consistently respect search terms and operators. It really is a can of worms you don't want to open. On top of all that, there is no easy way to export results.
The best idea is to choose different databases that are more search-friendly.
And to directly answer your question, to the best of my knowledge, there is no way to directly search only abstracts.

Thanks a lot! Will keep that in mind.
